how to disable system splash screen introduced in android 12 and above?
I'm encountering a problem identified in my pre-launch report on Google Play Store.
Check the attached image for clarification.
google play console pre-luanch report double splash screen warning
In my app, I have crafted a unique splash screen activity where I regulate network actions and present alert dialogues for various situations. Is there some method to turn off the default system splash screen on android 12 and later versions without replacing splash activity with splash screen API?
I have attempted the following approach,
 <style name="Theme.RemoveSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.style">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>       
   </style>  

However, this results in the splash screen's background becoming transparent, leading to a transparent backdrop during activity redirection.
I also tried the splash screen API, but it didn't work for me.

No way to remove the splash screen after Android 12.
You can use the above code only just set the postSplashScreenTheme
 <style name="Theme.RemoveSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.style">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>  
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">{default theme of your app}</item>
 </style>  


provided code cause background transparent while activity redirection.
